# Using PHP Variables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just wondering why this query returns nothing in PHP on the browswer, while it returns a good amount of items when used in the MySQL Workbench.

I am getting dates back by echoing both of these and then using the same dates and getting items returned in the MySQL Workbench.

```
$_POST['startdate']
$_POST['enddate']
```

So I am unsure why it doesn't work in the query. There are no PHP or MySQL errors/warnings that appear.

```
SELECT 
        mantis_category_table.name, 
        mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y") AS DATE2, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified), "%m-%d-%Y") AS FirstOfdate_modified,
        ROUND((min(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified)- mantis_bug_table.date_submitted)/ 86400, 1) as day_difference
    FROM (mantis_bug_table INNER JOIN mantis_bug_history_table 
    ON 
        mantis_bug_table.id = mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id) 
    INNER JOIN 
        mantis_category_table ON mantis_bug_table.category_id = mantis_category_table.id 
    WHERE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y")
            BETWEEN '.$_POST['startdate'].' AND '.$_POST['enddate'].'
    GROUP BY 
        mantis_category_table.name, mantis_bug_table.category_id, mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, mantis_bug_table.status, mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id, mantis_bug_history_table.field_name, mantis_bug_history_table.new_value 
    HAVING 
        (((mantis_bug_table.status)<>90) AND ((mantis_bug_history_table.field_name)="status") AND ((mantis_bug_history_table.new_value)="50")) 
    ORDER BY 
        mantis_category_table.name, mantis_bug_table.date_submitted'
```

The trouble seems to be this portion of the query. Is this invalid in MySQL? Is there a better way to do it?

```
    WHERE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y")
            BETWEEN '.$_POST['startdate'].' AND '.$_POST['enddate'].'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you echoed out the query with the POST variables and run it using MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Probably a concatenation issue.

Comment: `BETWEEN '".$_POST['startdate']."' AND '".$_POST['enddate']."'` give that a *whirl*

Comment: @Fred-ii- - It was actually more like this: `BETWEEN "'.$_POST['startdate'].'" AND "'.$_POST['enddate'].'"` - But if you write it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @navlag It has been done, *cheers* and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As per OP's wish:*

Concatenate your values like this:

```
BETWEEN "'.$_POST['startdate'].'" AND "'.$_POST['enddate'].'"
```

as you had missing quotes which are needed since we're dealing with string values.

Dates can contain hyphens (and colons) such as `2015-01-05 22:00` which will throw an SQL error.

However, I would like to point out that using this type of query is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should always escape user input before passing it to a query, or better yet, use prepared statements. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Second, you must make sure that the date values you receive from PHP are in the same format as those stored in your database. Since you are storing a unix time in your column, you could use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert your posted dates into a unix time suitable for direct comparison to the column values, or you could use [date_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) to convert them to a valid date format like you are attempting in your current comparison.